# Calculate the sum of a power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

If $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (x-1)^k$$
For $|x-1|<r$. Find the sum of the following series, and the values of x for which it converge
$$\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{(2k-1)a_k}{k^3-4k}(3x+2)^k$$
I feel so lost in this exercise so I don't even know how to begin with it. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

=== The given info tells us that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac1r$$

=== From the above:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(2n-1)a_n}{n^3-4n}\right|}=\frac1r$$

So you need to take $\;x\;$ in

$$|3x+2|<r\implies\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

The [**radius of convergence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of a series $\sum_k a_k\,(x-x_0)^k$ is the number

$$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}$$

From the hypothesis, we can conclude that $r\leq R$, that is $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}\leq \frac1r$.

The second series can be written as $\sum_k c_k\,{\left(x-\left(-\frac23\right)\right)}^k$, where

$$c_k=3^k\cdot\frac{2k-1}{k^3-4k}\cdot a_k$$

Now, notice that

$$\sqrt[k]{|c_k|}=3\cdot\underbrace{\sqrt[k]{\frac{2k-1}{k^3-4k}}}_*\,\,\cdot\sqrt[k]{|a_k|}$$

At this point, the problem reduces to two claims:

> **Claim $(1)$:** The limit of expression $*$ as $k\to\infty$ equals $1$.
>
> **Claim $(2)$:** If $\limsup_ {n\to\infty} b_n$ is finite and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists, then $$\limsup_ {n\to\infty} a_nb_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \cdot \limsup_ {n\to\infty} b_n.$$

From this, what can you conclude about $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|c_k|}$?